# How to get the object property dynamically in the run time using the name of the property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects

I have an object Structured like below.

[image]

Now what my intention is to get the Capitals/State value on the run time dynamically using the property name, for example.

```
var PropertyName='Capitals';
JSON.parse(ValueList)[0].PropertyName;
```

How to achieve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation(`[]`) for object selector

```
var PropertyName='Capitals';
JSON.parse(ValueList)[0][PropertyName];
```

For more about bracket notation : [visit here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Specifically, the values for Javascript object properties can be accessed using the dot notation (Object.property) or bracket notation (Object["property"]). See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets